# vsftpd + vitual users + selinux

Tags: ftp, pam, selinux

I can't make vsftpd to work and it is driving me crazy. The virtual users can connect, but they can't upload files or create folders. I hope someone can help me.

I get this error in the ftp client:

```
553 Could not create file
```

And this is the error in /var/log/messages

```
Jul 11 12:51:41 appserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1373557901.832:17): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=3705 comm="vsftpd" name="usr00" dev=dm-0 ino=2097155 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

This is my vsftpd.conf:

```
pasv_enable=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/ftp/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
```

This is my selinux configuration:

```
allow_ftpd_anon_write --> off
allow_ftpd_full_access --> off
allow_ftpd_use_cifs --> off
allow_ftpd_use_nfs --> off
ftp_home_dir --> on
ftpd_connect_db --> off
ftpd_use_passive_mode --> off
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
tftp_anon_write --> off
```

The test user is usr00. There is a folder /ftp/usr00 :

```
ls -Z /ftp
drwxr-xr-x. vsftpd vsftpd unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 cg00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried setting `public_content_rw_t` SELinux contest on the ftp rw dir? Or is there any reason why you don't want to do that?

```
chcon -t public_content_rw_t /ftp
ls -lZ /ftp
```

Comment: Thanks Petter, that was it. I also had to set allow_ftpd_anon_write to true and it worked.